# Expo EAS build fails on Android

Tags: react-native, expo

I upgraded my expo project to `expo 45.0.0` from `expo 41.0.0`.

While building the project using the command `eas build -p android`, it fails with the below errors. However, the ios build is fine.

Error Output:

```
FAILED
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/navigation_json/release/navigation.json'. Reason: Task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
[stderr] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
[stderr]    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
[stderr] > Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 7m 58s
```

For more details about the issue, you can visit:

https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1101

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have sorted this out by now..., but for anyone else: You need to add `android:exported="true"` to any `<activity>` that contains an `<intent-filter>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. However, I would recommend making a new project with the newer version of expo and then porting your relevant code over, it's generally less painful than dealing with numerous build issues...

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.leewannacott.libriaudire"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```